# Can Visual Studio, or another Tool, compare two pieces of code by behaviour?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When programming, there are often, if not always, multiple ways to get the exact same behaviour.

I know of a lot of Tools that allow literal line by line comparison of code files. What I'm looking for is a tool that can help, or do the entire work, when comparing behaviour.

I am well aware that side-effects, memory state, stack trace and many other things will be different in most cases at some point during execution. I'm really looking for a top-level comparison that wouldn't take all that into account. Just like a literal comparison tool can easily ignore blank lines and comments.

Here is an example:

1:

```
static void main()
{
    string i = "Hello World!";
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

2:

```
static void main()
{
    string helloWorldString = "Hello World!";
    Console.Write(helloWorldString);
}
```

3:

```
static void main()
{
    string myString = "Hello World!";
    WriteToConsole(myString);
}

static void WriteToConsole(string text)
{
    Console.Write(text);
}
```

Those 3 examples of simple Hello World programs **should** behave the same, at least from the user's point of view, extreme system configuration edge cases not included. I would expect the same machine to do exactly the same thing in all three cases.

Of course, this looks like a very difficult task for a computer to do fast, at least from my point of view. I wouldn't expect such a tool to be perfect, especially when the project has multiple classes, forms, global variables, etc.

But when doing some refactoring, getting a quick heads up like "With your changes, a behaviour has changed even though you hadn't noticed" or "The behaviour before and after your change stayed the same" would go a long way when it comes to saving time.

Is there such a tool in Visual Studio, Resharper, or available somewhere else?

As an extra exercise because I'm curious, if it doesn't exist for C#, does it exist for other languages? Are there known projects in progress for this?

Comment: I've got to think there's a slim chance of doing this with any reasonable accuracy.  It's not even possible to determine [if a program will *end* or not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) through static analysis.  It *might* be possible with snippets 1 and 2, since the only thing that has changed is a symbol name, but with snippet 3 I think you're sunk.

Comment: While it is technically impossible to prove a program will not end, it is very possible to automatically detect many types of infinite loops. I'm not sure if it was Visual Studio specifically, but I have received warnings in my life for while loops where the condition never changed several times, same goes for reversed for loops (increasing i, but testing if it goes below a threshold).

So while not technically possible with perfect accuracy, some tools can exist to help with a task regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. One problem is the Halting Problem which @BJMyers already mentioned in their comment. But another hindrance is that even your small snippets actually don't do the same thing. Let's look at the IL which is produced by them. First for #1:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello World!"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0008:  call        System.Console.Write
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

and for #2:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello World!"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // helloWorldString
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // helloWorldString
IL_0008:  call        System.Console.Write
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

Well, they are identical - which is no surprise, since the only difference is a variable name which doesn't exist in the compiled code anymore. But now for #3:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello World!"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // myString
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // myString
IL_0008:  call        UserQuery.WriteToConsole
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret         

WriteToConsole:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  call        System.Console.Write
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ret
```

As you can see it has 3 instructions more (not counting `nop` here). So your tool would need to inspect the IL and determine which outcome is produced by which input. And this would lead us back to the Halting Problem. Sure, a static analyzer could identify *some* patterns, but a genaral solution isn't possible.

If your target is to be sure that refactorings didn't break anything, the best you can do are unit tests, just as @dktaylor already suggested in their answer.

Comment: Unit testing, as mentioned in the comment of the other answer, are not what I had in mind. I had a vague idea that it would be too complex to do automatically and reliably, but your example put it in perspective. It is much much worse than I thought. I assume that we are still ver far from getting such a tool, so I accept your detailed answer :)

I believe that computer science and AI will someday be able to do it though.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can't statically analyze code behavior as it may depend on the environment like files and user input.

You can run a program and capture behavior as a sequence of method calls with parameter and return values using my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool:

```
void Program.Main([])
   void Program.WriteToConsole("Hello World!")
     void Console.Write("Hello World!")
      >SyncTextWriter Console.get_Out()
       void SyncTextWriter.Write("Hello World!")
         void StreamWriter.Write("Hello World!")
           void StreamWriter.CheckAsyncTaskInProgress()
          >void String.CopyTo(0, [�, �, �, �, �, �, �, �, �, ...246..., �], 0, 12)
           void StreamWriter.Flush(true, false)
            >12 EncoderNLS.GetBytes([H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, ...246..., �], 0, 12, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...247..., 0], 0, false)
            >void __ConsoleStream.Write([72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, ...247..., 0], 0, 12)
            >void __ConsoleStream.Flush()
```

But if your program generates graphic output or makes database changes you need other tools.

BTW, using automated tools to perform refactoring most certainly preserves program behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you’re looking for is unit testing. They allow you to test the result of some function without worrying about the implementation. Take a look here:

[Getting Started](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing)

Comment: I know very well that unit tests are. They indeed test behaviour in some mesure. The problem is, with Unit tests, the user has to find every single part of the behaviour he thinks is relevant, and make a test for it. Unit tests are about making sure some cases (nobody can ever test all of them) are behaving correctly, not about figurting out if the entire project is behaving the same. The kind of tool I am looking for would have no clue if the code is doing the right thing, it would just tell me if both versions are doing the same thing.